# Google Picasa Uploaded video direct download link via API

Tags: api, download, picasa, google-photos

I'm using Picasa API to upload videos:

```
https://developers.google.com/picasa-web/
```

I'm able to get links to streaming in this format:

```
https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/gJ36JMaguCcEdlVXOs5YP7huwtqbfp96sSHXLBvdnaE=m18
```

Is it possible to receive somehow direct link to download this video? Although there is no way for downloading Picasa Web, I can download movie from Google Photos (it's automatically synchronizes with Picasa) using this page:

```
https://picasaweb.google.com/lh/photo/3Jmth_jxsN-NpNn_QmWXcNMTjNZETYmyPJy0liipFm0
```

But I can't catch how it's downloading, because it's using some random token as download link.

Comment: You will have to look and see if they have an API.

Comment: Yes, I'm using Picasa API, but there is any download method provided in it. I'm looking for some workaround to download files. I know, that there was some way before, but now Google has changed format of streaming link and an old way is now working anymore.

Answer (score 0):

> You can't currently download original video files. However, you can
>   download the FLV video stream or the mp4 video stream by using the
>   URLs from the `<media:content>` video elements provided in the photo
>   entry or feed. There's one `<media:content>` element for each video
>   stream.

https://developers.google.com/picasa-web/docs/2.0/developers_guide_protocol#PostVideo Under limitations

Comment: Yes, I saw that. But, as I wrote before, I'm looking for some workaround to download files. I know, that there was some way before (even if on Picasa API site was info which you quoted), but now Google has changed format of streaming link and an old way is now working anymore.

Comment: The documentation says no. Even if you do find a workaround, it won't be reliable, and so you shouldn't use it. Consider using an alternative service if you want to do uploading and downloading of videos programtically.

Comment: @Relequestual On the contrary, the documentation says yes. You can't download the _original_ files, but you are supposed to be able to download mp4 and flv encoded files.

Comment: Only stream the mp4. The OP wants the mp4 format for download. flv encoded files is probably not what they are looking for.